# How do I split filenames from paths using python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of files that look like this:

Input

```
/foo/bar/baz/d4dc7c496100e8ce0166e84699b4e267fe652faeb070db18c76669d1c6f69f92.mp4
/foo/baz/bar/60d24a24f19a6b6c1c4734e0f288720c9ce429bc41c2620d32e01e934bfcd344.mp4
/bar/baz/foo/cd53fe086717a9f6fecb1d0567f6d76e93c48d7790c55e83e83dd1c43251e40e.mp4
```

And I would like to split out the filenames from the path while retaining both.

Output

```
['/foo/bar/baz/', 'd4dc7c496100e8ce0166e84699b4e267fe652faeb070db18c76669d1c6f69f92.mp4']
['/foo/baz/bar/', '60d24a24f19a6b6c1c4734e0f288720c9ce429bc41c2620d32e01e934bfcd344.mp4']
['/bar/baz/foo', 'd53fe086717a9f6fecb1d0567f6d76e93c48d7790c55e83e83dd1c43251e40e.mp4']
```

How would one go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[os.path.split](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.split#os.path.split) does exactly what you require, and I quote...:

```
os.path.split(path)
```

> Split the pathname path into a pair,
>   (head, tail) where tail is the last
>   pathname component and head is
>   everything leading up to that. The
>   tail part will never contain a slash;
>   if path ends in a slash, tail will be
>   empty. If there is no slash in path,
>   head will be empty. If path is empty,
>   both head and tail are empty. Trailing
>   slashes are stripped from head unless
>   it is the root (one or more slashes
>   only). In nearly all cases, join(head,
>   tail) equals path (the only exception
>   being when there were multiple slashes
>   separating head from tail).

So, given a list (named e.g. `paths`) of complete paths,

```
split_paths = [os.path.split(p) for p in paths]
```

should be exactly the list-of-tuples you desire.  If there's any actual reason that make you request a list-of-lists instead of the natural list-of-tuples, that's not hard to make:

```
split_paths_as_lists = [list(os.path.split(p)) for p in paths]
```